# array_shift shows warning if the variable has a null or empty value

Tags: php, arrays

I'm working on a MVC project and i'm on the part to get the URL values, to get each param i use [array_shift()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) and the documentation says this:

> Returns the shifted value, or **NULL** if array is empty or is not an
>   array.

In my code i have these lines:

```
        $arrParams = isset($_GET["params"]) ? explode("/", $_GET["params"]) : "";

        $controller = array_shift($arrParams);
        $action = array_shift($arrParams);
        $params = array_shift($arrParams);
```

If i access to `mvc-project.local` and i don't pass any param to the URL appears this message:

> Warning: array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in ... on line 12

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this -

```
    $arrParams = isset($_GET["params"]) ? explode("/", $_GET["params"]) : array();
```

Or

```
    (array) $arrParams = isset($_GET["params"]) ? explode("/", $_GET["params"]) : "";
```

Or

```
    $controller = array_shift((array)$arrParams);
    $action = array_shift((array)$arrParams);
    $params = array_shift((array)$arrParams);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are defaulting `$arrParams` to an empty string, so that is why you get a warning (note not an *error*) about it being passed a string. Just make it an empty array:

```
$arrParams = isset($_GET["params"]) ? explode("/", $_GET["params"]) : array();
```

Or a not so good solution is to suppress the warning with `@`:

```
$controller = @array_shift($arrParams);
$action = @array_shift($arrParams);
$params = @array_shift($arrParams);
```